# Can JabRef order by date instead of year?

Tags: jabref

Today I noticed JabRef orders my library "wrong" when I ask it to sort all articles through time. This turned out to be understandable, since I ordered by the column called Year. However, I did not manage to find a way to order by date. Does a way exist? Note that I do not mean the Date field, but the date derived from all entered fields related to time.
Thanks to anyone taking the time to reply.

Comment: Do you mean the *timestamp* field?

Comment: Hi Johannes. No, that would be the time I added a reference to my library.
What I mean is a date based on the fields `date`, `year`, `month`, and `day`. LaTeX seems to be able to translate these fields into a date when creating a bibliography. My hopes are JabRef has a similar method of interpreting these fields, so that references can be ordered by release date. (Ordering by release year gets confusing when over five sources came out in the same year, referencing each other.)

Comment: Ah, just put everything in the date field YYYY-MM-DD. That is fine with `biblatex` and should be fine with jabref as well.

Comment: Sounds like a solution and I would try it, but I'm unsure how to add that field as a column so I can sort by it.

Comment: Are you running Jabref in biblatex-mode? https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/split/jabrefBiblatexMode.png Know what you mean. Let me check how to teach Jabref to do that.

Comment: Yes, I am. And thanks for your answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for `biblatex` is to set the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

We can modify Jabref to show the `date` field, and hence make it easy to sort the list.

Go to options -> preferences and choose *Entry table columns*; add the date column as shown in the picture.

[image: jabrefAddDateColumn]

Comment: Since JabRef seems to be missing a feature to interpret dates the way biblatex does, manually populating the Date field and adding it to the entry table as a sortable column seems the best solution. Thanks.