# biblatex how to cite newspaper article showing date

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a newspaper article using biblatex with `bibstyle=authoryear`. But I'm not able to make visible in the bibliography the newspaper issue date. The only workaround found so far is to put the full date in the `note` field. For the rest of the bibliography the style is correct.

This is the entry:

```
@Article{Barone2006,
  Title                    = {Una intervista con Giacomo Rizzolatti},
  Author                   = {Luca Tancredi Barone},
  Journaltitle             = {Il manifesto},
  Year                     = {2006},
  Date                     = {2006-10-31}
}
```

And this is the result (language is Italian):

Barone, L. T. (2006). «Una intervista con Giacomo Rizzolatti». In: Il manifesto.

No sign of the full date even if I remove the `Year` field or if I set `Month` and `Day` fields.

Just for completeness, here are the package options:

```
\usepackage[%
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    language=auto,
    backend=biber,
    firstinits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false,
    urldate=comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    safeinputenc=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    clearlang=true,
    autolang=other]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You can use the `month` field for displaying the month of the issue. For example:`Month = {Jul}` But this does not display the day.

Comment: Does [Modifying citation style for newspaper articles in Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186205) give you any first clues?

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to leave this as "ultima ratio".

Comment: Discovered that adding `mergedate=basic` to biblatex options display the date, but displays also ugly (and not needed) dates for all the other entries. Back to the manual...

Comment: There is an origday, origmonth, and origyear option as defined in the biblatex documentation http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf . Also there is a Chicago-style biblatex that has built in options for origin dates.

Comment: Solved! Add `mergedate=basic` to the biblatex options, use correctly the `number` vs. `issue` fields (I wrongly assumed they are synonyms). Remove `month` where not needed (e.g., for a book) and now the newspaper is cited correctly. There are still `biber` warnings saying `date` overrides `year`, but I have to keep `year` to make JabRef happy. Hope this could help other people.

Comment: If you have found a good solution to your problem it is in no way frowned upon if you write up an answer yourself (indeed it is very much encouraged to do so).

Comment: Wanna keep Jabref happy? Try this [Can JabRef order by date instead of year?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1) Add `mergedate=basic` to the biblatex options, so I have:

```
\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,
    language=auto,
    backend=biber,
    firstinits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false,
    urldate=comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    safeinputenc=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    clearlang=true,
    maxcitenames=1,
    mergedate=basic,
    autolang=other]{biblatex}
```

2) Correct entries to use the `number` field for issue number. I had few entries where I mistakenly had put the issue number in the `issue` field. The result was something like (3 2004) hence my reference to "strange dates".

3) Remove `month` where not needed (e.g., for a book). Otherwise you have e.g. a (Mar. 1999) entry appears in bibliography.

Now the newspaper is cited correctly as:

Barone, L. T. (2006). «Una intervista con Giacomo Rizzolatti». In: Il manifesto (31 ott. 2006).

Leaving the rest of the entries unharmed. Then modified JabRef as Johannes_B suggested. It is not a global ordering by year **OR** date, but it is better than nothing. Thanks!